# Open an app built with Lightning App Builder in Developer Console

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I'm new to salesforce and maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree, but I created a simple lightning app using the Lightning App Builder and I am trying to open that app in the Developer Console.  I can't find it.

On the reverse side of the coin, I create an app in the developer console and I can't find it in the App Builder.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

I am using a developer version of salesforce, so this is not a matter of deploying it.  From the docs I've read, you can't deploy to a developer version anyway.

Using spring 2018 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages created or customized in the Lightning App Builder won't show up in the developer console because you're actually creating metadata, not code. If, as a developer, you want to make changes to those pages, I suggest you check out the [Flexipage Metadata Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_flexipage.htm).

When you create an "[App](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_intro.htm)" via the developer console, you're creating a standalone app using the Lightning Component Framework. These apps are not visible in App Builder. You can, however, create components in the developer console that can be put into App Builder pages. More information on how to do that is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_intro.htm).